# in Electron with react app how to solve blank white screen after restoring from minimized state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, electron

I've developed an Electron app with react content . in mac os after restoring app from minimized state it first shows a blank white screen and then it renders the page. How can I solve this issue? I have changed all BowserWindow options but it could not help. 
minimizing the app and then restoring cause a blank screen at first.

I also made electron app with electron-forge . same issue still there. I don't know how actually VSCode or What's app have solved this problem ?

Electron Installed Version "7.1.6"

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved in the newer updates of electron.Here is link
[Release Notes for v7.1.2](https://electronjs.org/releases/stable#release-notes-for-v712)

are you on same version?

Comment: I use "electron": "7.1.5" but problem is still there

Comment: @user1581036:It is issue of react. In react we have to add 
import React, {Suspense,  } from 'react'
 <Suspense fallback={<div />}> 
which is use for showing a blank div when transition one page to other.So in suspense you can put you loader and anything.